# Existence of non-degenerate line bundles on abelian schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $X$ be an abelian scheme over some base scheme $S$. Even without projectivity hypothesis, we may talk of the dual abelian scheme $\hat X$ of $X$. Given a line bundle $\mathcal L$ over $X$, the associated Mumford line bundle $\Lambda(\mathcal L) := \mu^*\mathcal L \otimes \mathrm{pr}_1^*\mathcal L^{-1}\otimes \mathrm{pr}_2^*\mathcal L^{-1}$ on $X\times_S X$ induces a homomorphism $\lambda_{\mathcal L}:X\rightarrow \hat X$. We say that the line bundle $\mathcal L$ is *non-degenerate* when the homomorphism $\lambda_{\mathcal L}$ is an isogeny.

> Is there always a non-degenerate line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $X$ ?

When the abelian scheme $X\rightarrow S$ is projective, any relatively ample line bundle on $X$ will do. In particular, this settles down the case where $S$ is noetherian normal, as any abelian scheme (even abelian algebraic space) over such an $S$ is automatically a projective scheme (see Faltings and Chai's book "Degeneration of Abelian Varieties", Remarks 1.10.a).

But what about the very general case, with no hypothesis on $S$ ?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128488/when-are-abelian-schemes-projective

Comment: @user45878 Thank you very much for the comment. The post on Mathoverflow gives conditions under which a relatively ample line bundle exists, and states that there are counter examples of abelian schemes with no such line bundle. Non-degeneracy is a slightly weaker condition though, as a non-degenerate line bundle is ample only when it has a nonzero global section. I wonder if we may still find some non-degenerate line bundle even when we have no projectivity, as I am unaware of any reference tackling the question...

Comment: Ah I see! Is there any particular reason you are interested in this question or context in which would you like to use a positive answer?

Comment: @user45878 Well, I don't exactly need it. I'm writing my Master Thesis on the topic of moduli of abelian varieties. While reviewing stuff on abelian scheme, this question came to me naturally, and I felt it would be nice to include an answer. This is not crucial though.. !